# Missing TextView data(text) in a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a few edittexts and textviews in Fragment A. I use edittexts to get value from user and then I calculate based on my formula and show the result in the textview.

For example Edittext A has 1 and Edittext B has 2 and my formula is add so the textview will show the result as 3.

Also, there is a button, info on the Fragment A. On clicking this button a new fragment B is displayed using the below code:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contentFrag, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStackStateName);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Now, when I press the back button, I let the system call super.onBackPressed() so that the current Fragment B is removed and I get back Fragment A.

MY PROBLEM:

Now the edittexts retain all their values, however the value I calculated and displayed on TextViews disappears.

I checked onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) method however the parameter savedInstanceState is null.

My Question:

How do I save/retrieve the values for my textviews?

OR

where can I call that code again that calculates the data for textviews ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem you need use some data layer like Shared Preference or SQL storage. In some primitive way it looks like:

```
 public override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                                     savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

        //update you UI from local STORAGE on create
        textView.text = sharedPreference.getInt("result_data", 0).toString()//make request local for date


        //calling your calculation
        button.setOnClickListener {

            calculateData(dataInput, object : Callback {
                override fun onCalculated() {

                    //update you UI from local STORAGE layer in MAIN THREAD
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        textView.text = sharedPreference.getInt( 
                                  "result_data",0
                          ).toString()
                    }
                }

            })
        }
    }

//you calculate and request to data layer

    private fun calculateData(inPutData:Int, callback:Callback){

           //use background for calculate It will be available. 
           Thread{

                //calculate
                val result = inPutData+ ARG_PARAM 

                //save result in LOCAL STORAGE
                sharedPreference.edit().putInt( " result", result).apply()

               //update UI 
               callback.onCalculated()

            }.start()

        }

    interface Callback{
        fun onCalculated()

    }
```

Think also about MVP and Presenter. It is also be available. 
In open source you can find amazing MVP library called [moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy). It can restore your view state.

Comment: Sorry but I am just a beginner in android programming, I managed to convert your Kotlin code to Java to understand it, but I didnt understand why you do this twice "textView.text = sharedPreference.getInt( "result_data",0).toString()" and that too on a different thread ?

Comment: @Harshad Loya I do not do this twice. It is different moment. First on fragment view creatred , next on calculated from callback. You can create one function for this and call it from this points.

Comment: it call in one main tread - ui update. But callculate available do in background thread

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use it as well, I used the idea from this and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences will solve your issue just save them in sharedPreferences and clear SharedPreference after Use.

Comment: Is SharedPreferences something similar to the savedInstanceState ?

Comment: no its different from savedInstancesState savedInstanceState will delete the data after the is forced stopped but SharedPreferences will not delete the data until you uninstall the App or you clear the sharedpreferences